# OpenID single username

Tags: python, django, openid, single-sign-on, registration

I have created a django multi-sites under single django code base, where every site have his own domain and own database. I use **OpenID** for Login/SignUp.

My problem is this: when a user is registering via OpenID is required for him to make a username, for each site. Why?

Is there a way to maintain a **single username** for all sites like *stackexchange*?

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: I have Python Openid 2.2.5 library. I tried to follow this guide: http://www.netvivs.com/openid-recipe/ but I do not understood if I must to create a database only for OpenID?